# rails friendly_id and check if entry exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

How to check if [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) entry exists before get it?

For example:

```
  def book
   @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  end
```

It's ok, but i want check before if friendly_id exists, something like:

```
def book
  if Book.exists?(params[:book_id])
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  else
    #404 not found
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rescue from RecordNotFound exception ==>

```
def book
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  #OK
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  head :not_found
end
```

Comment: `find_by_id` will return instance or nil. While `find` or `find_by_id` will raise exception

Comment: thanks, corrected the answer. Copy paste always leads to trouble!!

Answer (score 18):

As of the latest version of the `friendly_id` gem, you can say:

```
Book.friendly.exists? params[:book_id]
```

Comment: This is so much better than the accepted answer. Exceptions should only be for things you can't easily predict - not things you expect to happen.

Comment: if you use :finders you can probably omit friendly, resulting in `Book.exists? params[:book_id]`

Comment: Dangerous. Any slug that starts with a number will return false positives since it will fall back on ActiveRecord's finder, and "1something".to_i == 1

Comment: @StephenCorwin Yes, that's why I don't mix in the "finders" module into my model.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to move Deepak N's solution to model like I did:

```
def self.find_by_friendly_id(friendly_id)
  find(friendly_id)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  nil
end
```

So now it will fetch your books by both id and slug and won't throw exception, just like standard AR method #find_by_id.

BTW, according the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/FinderMethods) #exists?
 method now is right way to check record existance!

Answer (score -2):

```
@book = Book.find_by_id(params[:book_id])
if @book
  # OK
else
  #404 not found
enв
```